# How is the variational lower bound for hard attention derived in Show, Attend and Tell

Tags: papers, math, attention, evidence-lower-bound

How is the jump from line 1 to line 2 done in equation 10 of [Show, Attend and Tell](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03044.pdf)?

[image]

While we're at it, another thing that might be muddying the waters for me is that I'm not clear on what the sum is over. I know that $s$ is indexed as $s_{t,i}$, but the one-hot trick from line 2 to 3 makes me believe that the sum is over just $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) at work.

First of all, note that the first line can be rewritten as an expectation

$$\sum_{s} p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) = \mathbb{E}_{p(s|a)}[\log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})]$$

Then Jensen's inequality gives (Note that a log function is a **concave** function so gives the opposite inequality to what is normally given when explaining Jensen's inequality with respect to convex functions):

$$\mathbb{E}_{p(s|a)}[\log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})] \leq \log\mathbb{E}_{p(s|a)}[ p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})] $$

and then finally you can rewrite the Expectation as a summation.

$$\log\mathbb{E}_{p(s|a)}[ p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})] = \log \sum_{s} p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})$$